# select2 sending id instead of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jquery-select2

I am making a erp website for that I am using select2 to auto fill products I am initializing select2 using an array that I create from the data that I receive from the server(products is an array of objects containing all the product details)

```
let data = products.map(product =>{return {id : product._id , text : product.product_name}});
//data = [{id : 1, text : 'al00'},{id : 2, text : 'al01'},{id : 3, text : 'al03'}]


$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
    data : data
});
```

The frontend looks perfect I am getting all the product names in the webpage

```
.js-example-basic-single is a select input in the form
```

when I submit this form I am getting id of the elements instead of the name of elements

```
      <form
        action="/create-barcodes"
        id="create-barcodes-form"
        method="POST">
        <div id="barcode-wrapper">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="size">Product</label>
            <div id="barcode-select-container">
              <select
                class="js-example-basic-single form-control"
                id="barcode"
                name="barcode">
              </select>
            </div>
            <label for="quantity">quantity</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              class="form-control mt-2"
              name="quantity"
              id="quantity"/>

          </div>
        </div>
        <input
          type="submit"
          class="btn btn-primary"
          value="Generate"
          id="generate-barcode"/>
      </form>
```

response I am receiving

```
{ barcode: '2', quantity: '52' }
```

response I am expecting

```
{ barcode: 'al01', quantity: '52' }
```

Comment: Just retain the `product_name`, and transform the data using map again.

Comment: @AluanHaddad can you please elaborate on that I do not understand what you are trying to say